# Best way to deploy Powershell 4.0 on Windows 7 sp1 and server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, powershell

I am planning to deploy powershell 4.0 on all Win 7 and server 2008 and 2008R2.

I did some research about this, but couldn't find the official way to do it. I can just use batch file or GPO to install it for sure, just wondering if there is any official deployment tool for this?

Is there anyone who had experience before that can share with me?

1. Windows Management Framework 4 OR 5 (**Do I need to install WMF5?** This just released)
2. .NET Framework 4.5
3. Powershell web access

Comment: WMF4 includes Powershell 4. You don't *need* WMF5 to get Powershell 4.

Comment: but wmf5 have lot of powershell updates, not worth?

Comment: WMF5 is still a *preview* release as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy .NET and WMF via WSUS or SCCM.  WMF 5 is still in preview, and would not work on 2008R2 or Win7 anyway, so no, don't worry  about WMF 5.  Deploy .NET first, as it is a prerequisite of WMF.

Powershell Web Access is something you would set up on one server - your "gateway."  Don't deploy Powershell Web Access on every server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831611.aspx

Edit: Also, Powershell Remoting is enabled by default in Server 2012 onwards, but not so for 2008 R2/Win7. You can enable Powershell Remoting on your clients via Group Policy just like this guy does it: http://blog.powershell.no/2010/03/04/enable-and-configure-windows-powershell-remoting-using-group-policy/

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you deploy software period. I use sccm, but for the packaging I prefer SFX's where simple .msi's or similar cannot be done. If you don't have such a luxury, The .msu can be installed silently using the `/quiet` switch, I also prefer the `/norestart` switch to keep calls down from users.

Comment: even can be done by gpo, but i still prefer /quiet

Comment: @RootLoop Please, *don't*.